# DBA's Checklist for performance tuning

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, database-administration, sql-server-administration

In our production environment, Some times server becomes too slow, even good optimized queries start facing timeout error & some even get blocked.

1. What are the basic things that could cause this slowdown ?
2. I'm very new to these type of activities, Please suggest me the articles to read and guidelines to follow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is too openended and would invite answers which might not be related to your environment. The post would be put on HOLD. There can be MANY reasons for SQL Server to be slow it IMPOSSIBLE to list all.

Comment: Yes I agree. Nevertheless there is something common. As Im very new to this your checklist may help me allot.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a very broad question I'll give a very generalist answer.

There are 2 approaches you can take to get a basic idea what your bottleneck is and start investigating from there.

SQL server can give you insight through "Wait stats", there is a myriad of information to be found on google for this. [This post by Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/wait-stats/) is a good starting point

You can also use performance counters to get insight about what is going wrong (not enough memory, slow IO, a lot of table scans, ...). Again [Brent Ozar explains it well](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/).

Once you get a basic idea about what the issue might be you will need to start digging deeper into it